# Collapsing toolbar not collapsing on scrolling in cordinator layout

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I've used Collapsing Toolbar in Cordinator Layout but still the Collapsing bar just dont collapse and remains still on scrolling.

This is activity_demo.xml -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<!-- Fit the system windows for your CollapsingToolbarLayout
           also set your height to wrap_content and give image a height-->

<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="4dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="244dp"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/cheese"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>
                <!-- Tell your toolbar to scroll|enterAlways -->
                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
                <!-- add layout_gravity="bottom" -->
                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="24dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Info"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin">

                    <LinearLayout
                        style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Friends"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin">

                    <LinearLayout
                        style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Related"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/cheese_ipsum" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is DemoActivity.java -

```
    package com.example.priyanshu.iitmandi;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

public class DemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_demo);

        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
                (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Faculty");

        loadBackdrop();
    }

    private void loadBackdrop() {
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backdrop);

        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cheese);
    }

}
```

If screenshot of the activity is needed then let me know

Comment: compare here : http://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout#creating-collapsing-effects

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this suggestions:

1.you didn't add `app:layout_scrollFlags` to the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"  //add this
app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
```

2.Next thing put the `<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` out of `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and add it under `AppBarLayout`

3.In your `NestedScrollview`  add `android:fillViewport="true"` sometimes it gives the desired output.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
```

**EDIT**

you can also try for `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
```

and for `Toolbar`

```
app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
```

it will pin the toolbar during scrolling..

Comment: Thanks man!! it worked, but a little issue is there that on scrolling the collapsing toolbar completely dissappears(that is both image and title disappears) instead i want it to shrunk to small size and stay there(that is only title should be displayed)

Comment: try using: `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"`  to know more about the flags : http://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout#creating-collapsing-effects

Comment: Error:(22, 37) String types not allowed (at 'layout_scrollFlags' with value 'scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollap‌​sed').    This error is displayed on adding the scroll flag you just suggested

Comment: it is the same property you added previously in `CollapsingToolbarLayout`...just edit it with the new..